# React: How to solve graphql/ react query error "Parse error on.."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-query

Here I am trying to get QRcode details by calling graphql query : showQrCode. The code is as follows.

get id using useParams(). Then called useQrCode()

```
...
const params = useParams();
const { data } = useQrCode(params.id);
...
```

and also pass the id

```
...
export const listQrcode = async (id: any) => {
    console.log("inside list qrcode")
  const result = await useFormProvider(showQrCode, {id});
  return result.data
}

export const useQrCode = (id: any) => {
    console.log("inside useqrcode", id)
  return useQuery(['share-survey-qrcode', id], () => listQrcode(id), {
    enabled: !!id,
  });
};
...
```

query:

```
export const showQrCode = gql`
query qrcodeUrlByFormId (id: $id!){
    qrcodeUrl
  }
}
`;
```

Postman :
[image]

But here I am facing an issue. I am new to using grapgql query, Is there any issues?

Error:
[image]

I refer some documents to fix this but failed. I don't know how to fix this problem. Please give me some suggestions to fix this problem

> Error: Parse error on "id" (IDENTIFIER) at [2, 26]: {"response":{"errors":[{"message":"Parse error on "id" (IDENTIFIER) at [2, 26]","locations":[{"line":2,"column":26}]}],"status":200,"headers":{"map":{"cache-control":"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"}}},"request":{"query":"\nquery qrcodeUrlByFormId (id: $id!){\n    qrcodeUrl\n  }\n}\n","variables":{"id":"57ab92d3-b611-43bb-8e6f-270503c42500"}}}

Comment: `showQrCode` has a closing curly bracket too many.

Comment: I fixed that but there is an error : "Error: Parse error on "id" (IDENTIFIER) at [2, 26]: {"response":{"errors":[{"message":"Parse error on \"id\" (IDENTIFIER) at [2, 26]","locations":[{"line":2,"column":26}]}],"status":200,"headers":{"map":{"cache-control":"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"}}},"request":{"query":"\nquery qrcodeUrlByFormId (id: $id!){\n    qrcodeUrl\n  }\n","variables":{"id":"57ab92d3-b611-43bb-8e6f-270503c42500"}}}"

Comment: Take a closer look at [how variables work with queries](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables).