# Error: Field 'qrcodeUrl' doesn't exist on type 'Query'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, graphql

Here I am trying to get QRcode details by calling graphql query : showQrCode. The code is as follows.

get id using useParams(). Then called useQrCode()

```
...
const params = useParams();
const { data } = useQrCode(params.id);
...
```

and also pass the id

```
...
export const listQrcode = async (id: any) => {
    console.log("inside list qrcode")
  const result = await useFormProvider(showQrCode, {id});
  return result.data
}

export const useQrCode = (id: any) => {
    console.log("inside useqrcode", id)
  return useQuery(['share-survey-qrcode', id], () => listQrcode(id), {
    enabled: !!id,
  });
};
...
```

query:

```
export const showQrCode = gql`
query qrcodeUrlByFormId ($id: ID){
    qrcodeUrl
  }
`;
```

Postman :
[image]

But here I am facing an issue. I am new to using grapgql query, Is there any issues?

> query.ts:436 Error: Field 'qrcodeUrl' doesn't exist on type 'Query': {"response":{"errors":[{"message":"Field 'qrcodeUrl' doesn't exist on type 'Query'","locations":[{"line":3,"column":5}],"path":["query qrcodeUrlByFormId","qrcodeUrl"],"extensions":{"code":"undefinedField","typeName":"Query","fieldName":"qrcodeUrl"}},{"message":"Variable $id is declared by qrcodeUrlByFormId but not used","locations":[{"line":2,"column":1}],"path":["query qrcodeUrlByFormId"],"extensions":{"code":"variableNotUsed","variableName":"id"}}],"status":200,"headers":{"map":{"cache-control":"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"}}},"request":{"query":"\nquery qrcodeUrlByFormId ($id: ID){\n    qrcodeUrl\n  }\n","variables":{"id":"79991ef5-275f-4830-b492-df95df846dd0"}}}

I refer some documents to fix this but failed. I don't know how to fix this problem. Please give me some suggestions to fix this problem

Comment: Why are you reposting [your exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73892364/react-how-to-solve-graphql-react-query-error-parse-error-on)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: How to solve graphql/ react query error "Parse error on.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73892364/react-how-to-solve-graphql-react-query-error-parse-error-on)

Comment: I am trying to fix it. But still there are some errors, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: Just edit your previous question. Make sure you also include your schema.